# How put the button beside the textbox directly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

As you know, in ASP.NET, there is a simple space between the button and textbox. I want to remove this space and put them besides each other directly without any space. How to do that?

My CSS file:

```
.input, .button {
margin:-10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

My ASP.NET code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="input" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
</form>
```

And when I rendered it in IE 8 Browser, nothing happened. I don't know why. Any help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

That has less to do with ASP.NET and more to do with the default CSS values a browser applies to the elements on the page.

That being said, adding a CSS rule of...

```
input, button {
    margin:0;
}
```

should work...

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to use margins, make sure you do not add a line return in your markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Button" /><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="input" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

That line return gets rendered as a space by most browsers.

Otherwise, something like this works: http://jsfiddle.net/a4TPt/

Answer (score 1):

Your layout details would be helpful. But I think margin: -5 0 0 0 on the control on right side should work for what you are looking for. You need to adjust -5 to correct value as per your needs.